# Why doesn't cypress see the css value of the border * property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, integration-testing, cypress

```
cy.get("[data-e2e='dispatcher-checkbox'] i[data-e2e='checkbox']").should(
        "have.css",
        "border-radius",
        convertToRGB(theme("colors.greys.2")),
      )
```

All other property values ​​are seen, but the values ​​of properties starting with border and the border itself, says that the `value = ""`

[image]

Comment: can you post the screenshot of the error as well in the question.

Comment: Since `.should('have.prop','property')` returns the value I think the path to validate the css is the next one:

`cy.get("[data-e2e='dispatcher-checkbox'] i[data-e2e='checkbox']")
    .should("have.css", "border-radius")
cy.get("[data-e2e='dispatcher-checkbox'] i[data-e2e='checkbox']")
    .should("have.css", convertToRGB(theme("colors.greys.2")))
)
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it turns out it's because of jQuery's behavior, it doesn't understand shortcut properties, it needs to specify "border-top-radius" in full.

Example:

```
cy.get("[data-e2e='dispatcher-checkbox'] i[data-e2e='checkbox']").should(
        "have.css",
        "border-top-radius",
        convertToRGB(theme("colors.greys.2")),
      )
```

**UPD:**
"border-radius" also works, but only if you do not call "it" in which the "border-radius" function is "only". Strange ...